# Creating scatter plot where symbol height/width is controlled by 2 variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am very new to R, and am trying to create a scatter plot in ggplot2 which is in affect a scatter plot where each symbol is controlled in its width and height by two variables.  I have come up with a work around using geom_errorbar and geo_errorbarh (code below) which is producing something along the lines I am looking for, but I want to be able to remove the error x/y mid cross lines and just leave a box for each datapoint, which I can colour in (I only need them to be in one colour).  An example of the type of thing I am talking about is at: http://imbie.org/about-the-project/ice-sheet-mass-balance-measurements/

A subset of my data is (I hope I have used dput() correctly):

```
structure(list(Year = c(2000L, 1995L, 1986L, 1977L, 1977L, 1973L, 
1973L, 1969L, 1965L, 1961L), RSL = c(0.02, 0.02, 0, -0.01, -0.07, 
0, -0.11, -0.1, -0.16, -0.07), Age_error = c(2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L), RSL_error = c(0.03, 0.04, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.05, 0.03, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.03), plus_error = c(0.05, 0.06, 
0.03, 0.02, -0.02, 0.03, -0.06, -0.05, -0.11, -0.04), minus_error = c(-0.01, 
-0.02, -0.03, -0.04, -0.12, -0.03, -0.16, -0.15, -0.21, -0.1), 
plus_age = c(2002L, 1996L, 1991L, 1981L, 1980L, 1977L, 1976L, 
1971L, 1967L, 1964L), minus_age = c(1998L, 1994L, 1981L, 
1973L, 1974L, 1969L, 1970L, 1967L, 1963L, 1958L), total_RSLerror = c(0.06, 
0.08, 0.06, 0.06, 0.1, 0.06, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.06), total_Ageerror = c(4L, 
2L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L)), .Names = c("Year", 
"RSL", "Age_error", "RSL_error", "plus_error", "minus_error", 
"plus_age", "minus_age", "total_RSLerror", "total_Ageerror"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c  ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

The code I have currently got is:

```
    ggplot(data, aes(x=Year, y=RSL)) + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=minus_error, ymax=plus_error, width=total_Ageerror)) + geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax=plus_age, xmin=minus_age, height=total_RSLerror)) + theme_bw()
```

Thank you ever so much in anticipation.  Please let me know if I need to send anything else or if I have inputed this incorrectly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use different shapes for every point in ggplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720313/how-to-use-different-shapes-for-every-point-in-ggplot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it with `geom_rect()` and using your `plus_` and `minus_` variables as `max` and `min` coordinates (named your data as `df`).

```
ggplot(df,aes(xmin=minus_age,xmax=plus_age,ymin=minus_error,ymax=plus_error))+
  geom_rect(fill="green",color="black")
```

[image]

Comment: You are an absolute legend Didzis.  That is so much easier than I was trying to achieve.  Thank you so so much.